# Having inheritance and polymorphism issues with Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I also need a overridden calclatefees method to calculate late fees for overdue movies.

```
 public class Action extends Movie {

    protected double latecost;
    protected double latefees;

    public Action (String title, String rating, int id, int rentTime, 
            double latecost, double latefees ) {

        super(title, rating, id, rentTime);
        this.title = title;
        this.rating= rating; 
        this.id = id; 
        this.rentTime=  8;
        this.latecost =  2;

        System.out.println( "Overridden " + title + rating + " " + id + " " 
                + latecost + " " + latefees);
    }
    public double calclatefees (double latecost) {

        if (rentTime > 3)
            latefees = ((rentTime - 3) * latecost);
        return latefees;}

    @Override
   public String toString () {
    String x = "Movie: " + title + " is rated "  + rating + "\nMovie ID           number:" 
            + id + " late fees are $" + latefees;
    return x;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Some output would be helpful.

Comment: aside the issue you re having, consider to refactor Action,Comedy and Drama to an enumerator, the are better attributes of a movie instead of inherited movies... :)

Comment: I am trying to see why my toString isn't sending back my values I put in my overloaded constructor and why they still won't when I assign them in my super.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this prints:

```
overloaded - not overridden  NR 00
overridden
```

Which is perfect. It demonstrates that constructors are treated specially. They all call the parent constructor first.

You are therefore seeing the constructor of the `Movie` printing *overloaded - not overridden  NR 00*, then the constructor of `Action` kicks in and prints *overridden*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the this keyword. I believe that if you do not and you are using the same names in the constructor, it isn't assigning anything. You are telling the title within the parameter to equal whatever you are assigning it, which in the example below is " not overridden ".

for example

```
public Movie(String title, String racing, int id, int rentTime){
   this.title = " not overridden ";
   // probably should be something like this.title = title after debugging.
   //etc...
}
```

The this keyword refers to the current object's data members, so this.title would be the Movie's title, not the parameter member title.

You will need to do this with your set methods above also.

```
public void rating (String rating) {this.rating = rating;}
```

edit: try this for constructor

```
public Movie(String title, String rating, int id, int rentTime){
    this.title = " not overridden ";
    this.rating = " NR ";
    this.id = 0;
    this.rentTime = 0;
    System.out.println( " overloaded -" + title + rating + id + rentTime);
 }
```

after you see the output, if you want to show the actual values you are passing into the other child classes, you have to change it to this:

```
public Movie(String title, String rating, int id, int rentTime){
    this.title = title;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.id = id;
    this.rentTime = rentTime;
    System.out.println( " overloaded -" + title + rating + id + rentTime);
 }
```

Comment: Can I get my child class toStrings to print the values from my array main method?

Comment: Yes, but right now you aren't having any values to print. Is your toString method right now showing anything at all? Maybe just the Strings literals that you put in? Also make sure that above your toString method you have the @Override annotation

Comment: I have the @Override but how do I display more than just the literals?

Comment: Like I said, you have to change the constructor for Movie. You have to assign the title and such values by using the this keyword. I'll make an edit above that you can try out.

Comment: I have been working on it still and my calclatefees isn't working.

Comment: what isn't working about it? What is the value getting printed?